# Doing math while updating Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a small invoicing solution and I Need to add a column to store the price of one unit. I already have a column for total for all the units and the quantity in the db.

My question is, how can I add this column and populate it with accurate numbers? I know that formula will be:

`total_col / quantity_col = unit_col`

Comment: Do not create a column. Calculate at query time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your database is called `mydb`, the table is called `invoices`, and the column is `unit_col` I would do the following:

Connect to your postgresql database via command line, typically `psql mydb` and then the following:

```
ALTER TABLE invoices 
ADD COLUMN unit_col real;

UPDATE invoices SET unit_col = total_col/quantity_col;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of populating a new column with some derived value:

```
create table products (
  total_col int,
  quantity_col int);

ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN unit_col numeric(10,2) default null;
update products set unit_col=total_col::float / quantity_col;
```

You'll want to set up a trigger to keep this column up to date. This is what is know as a persistent, computed column.

Another, perhaps better, solution is to set up a view that has the computed column you want:

```
create table products (
  total_col int,
  quantity_col int);

create view productsWithUnitCol as
  select *, total_col::float / quantity_col as unit_col from products;
```